# Problems with installing SFML

Tags: c++, gcc, sfml

(note: I am aware I have posted this on GameDev SE, but it got closed there)

I've followed the instructions on [installing SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php) on the website to the letter. But, I get this when I try to build the sample program on the same page using Code::Blocks.

```
C:\Users\nic\Desktop\sfmltest.o:sfmltest.cxx|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'|

...

||=== Build failed: 20 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I get 20 error messages, which are all similar to the one given above. SFML worked like a charm on my ubuntu 14.04 amd64 install, but it simply does not work on Windows. I am using SFML 2.1 (the GCC 4.7 TDM (SJLJ) - 64 bits package as the other ones did not work) on a Windows 7 x64 installation with MinGW (gcc 4.8.1). How can I make SFML work on Windows?

Comment: How did you try to build the program, or more specifically: How does the Code::Blocks project-file look like? Does your gcc work for simple hello world programs?

Comment: gcc works for simple Hello World programs. I have not made a project file to do it, instead I have changed global compiler settings.

Comment: Did you link the SFML-libraries correctly? I don't know if SFML provides a CB-project-file for the sample program, but if so, you should try building it using that project-file. Furthermore: What do your compiler settings look like?